# which sorting is the best sorting and why

Tags: data-structures

in data structures which is the best sorting among all those

Comment: This isn't even a question. "best sorting among all those" ... ? Among all those what?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "best sorting" because the performance of a given algorithm depends on how the initial data is given. Optimized Bubble sort can be faster than insertion sort if the initial data is given in a certain order, but this can be the opposite for another given data.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, in which cases is bubble sort faster than insertion sort?

Comment: There is a mistake in what I've said. Bubble sort is more of a "easiest way to implement sort", and doesn't have any other advantages beside that easiness. But that's not the case for insertion VS selection. There is an excellent website that shows interactively how sorting method works. You can even check how an algorithm will compute with nearly-sorted sets, and check by yourself
https://visualgo.net/en/sorting